# pandas scraping dataframe: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 21, 2)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to extract a list from a webpage and turn it into a dataframe. I am using the following code

```
  url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/info/business-economy-euro/banking-and-finance/financial-supervision-and-risk-management/anti-money-laundering-and-counter-terrorist-financing/eu-policy-high-risk-third-countries_en'
EU = pd.read_html(url)

print(EU)

df = pd.DataFrame(EU)
```

I get the following error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 21, 2)

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.DataFrame(EU[0])`?

Comment: That worked! And of course, that makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://ec.europa.eu/info/business-economy-euro/banking-and-finance/financial-supervision-and-risk-management/anti-money-laundering-and-counter-terrorist-financing/eu-policy-high-risk-third-countries_en'
EU = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(EU[0])
```